# Pipe no such file or directory

Tags: python, c++, ipc, named-pipes, fifo

I am trying to create a named pipe with C++ and reading it on python. This is my code:

```
const int MAX_BUF = 1024;
string wr_string = "Hi.";
char text[MAX_BUF] = "";
strcpy(text, wr_string.c_str());
int fd = open("/tmp/test", O_WRONLY);   // Open the pipe
write(fd,text,MAX_BUF);              // Write
close(fd);                                  // Close the pipe - allow the read
```

And I am reading it this way:

```
import os
import time

pipe = open("/tmp/OKC_avgprice", "r")
line = pipe.read() 
pipe.close()   

print line
```

However, everytime I try to read it this is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ipc.py", line 4, in <module>
    pipe = open("/tmp/test", "r")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/test'
```

When writing the pipe should be created automatically no? Why is it not found then?

Thanks!

Comment: Your error and the code you gave us are different. Can you check everything is exactly as you have run it, otherwise it's hard to problem solve.

Comment: That's not really a pipe, it's just an ordinary file.

Comment: You create a named pipe or a fifo with `mkfifo(3)` in C. Also your C"++" code is printing garbage to the pipe.

Comment: As for your problem, you really need to check for errors in the C++ code. Do the `open` call really succeed?

Comment: @Lattyware not actually...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg not actually... just noticed when looking at it again: `open` does not specify `O_CREAT` so no file is ever created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C++ code is not creating a named pipe; you must first create the named pipe with `mkfifo`(3):

```
mkfifo("/tmp/test", 0600) // 0600 means writable and readable by owner only
```

Such a fifo will show up on `ls -laF` (GNU) as

```
prw-------  1 user  group     0 Apr 12 07:02 test|
```

Notably, the line will start with `p` and there will be a `|` after the name.
The pipe will persist on the disk yes (though `/tmp` is usually emptied on reboots).

---

Do note that if you try to open a file with `O_WRONLY`, but the file **does not exist**, `open` will fail with `ENOENT`, returning `-1` as the `fd`. `open` will never try to create a new file with only `O_WRONLY`; to create a new *regular* file you need to call

```
open("/tmp/test", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0600);
```

where 0600 is the desired mode/permissions for the file.

Calling `write` and `close` with `-1` will subsequently fail with `EBADF`. **Please understand that you *must always* check the return values of all system calls**. Sometimes in Stackoverflow examples they are omitted for brevity, it should be general knowledge that one will need to add the checks.

---

To write the contents of a C++ `string`, write directly from the `.c_str()`:

```
write(fd, wr_string.c_str(), wr_string.length());
```

---

Also always check the error codes from C functions; `mkfifo`, `open`, `write` might fail, and they return a value `< 0`, and you need to be prepared to handle these cases.

Comment: Interesting. Do I need to create a named pipe with mkfifo everytime (even in python)? I thought just by writing to it it was going to be created automatically?